# How does this "Number to Roman" shell script work?

Tags: bash, shell

i'm beginning with bash, and i want to understand this example... If one of you can help me understanding the "to_roman" function, i'll be very grateful! or if you have some documentation for help, thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash
LIMIT=200
E_ARG_ERR=65
E_OUT_OF_RANGE=66

if [ -z "$1" ]
then
  echo "Usage: `basename $0` number-to-convert"
  exit $E_ARG_ERR
fi  

num=$1
if [ "$num" -gt $LIMIT ]
then
    echo "Out of range!"
    exit $E_OUT_OF_RANGE
fi  

to_roman ()
{
    number=$1
    factor=$2
    rchar=$3
    let "remainder = number - factor"
    while [ "$remainder" -ge 0 ]
    do
        echo -n $rchar
        let "number -= factor"
        let "remainder = number - factor"
    done  
    return $number
}

to_roman $num 100 C
num=$?
to_roman $num 90 LXXXX
num=$?
to_roman $num 50 L
num=$?
to_roman $num 40 XL
num=$?
to_roman $num 10 X
num=$?
to_roman $num 9 IX
num=$?
to_roman $num 5 V
num=$?
to_roman $num 4 IV
num=$?
to_roman $num 1 I
echo
exit
```

Comment: Say `set -x` before executing your script.  You should be able to see pretty much everything that's happening.

Answer (score 1):

The `to_roman ()` is a function definition and not part of the program itself. The actual program starts below that.

before `to_roman ()`, the program is simply verifying your input. Did you include a parameter? If not, the first `if` statement will catch that.

Is the number greater than 200? If it is greater than 200, the second `if` will take care of that.

The heart of the program is:

```
to_roman $num 100 C
num=$?
to_roman $num 90 LXXXX
num=$?
to_roman $num 50 L
num=$?
```

The program is running the `to_roman` function with the three parameters. The first is the number you want to convert (or what's left of that number. The second is the *factor* of that number, and the third is the character to print.

The program, is using a loop. For example, if I pass in the parameters `175`, `100`, and `C` into the `to_roman` function, it subtracts `150 - 100`, sees the results are still greater than 0, and prints out the letter `C` and tries again. In this case, it tries it once more, but gets the number `-25`. Since it's less than zero, the subroutine exits with `75`. The `num=$?` sets `number` with the leftover (amount `75` in this case).

This is done for `to_roman 75 90 LXXXX` (which doesn't print out anything because `90 - 75` is less than zero), `to_roman 75 50 L` (which prints out a single `L` because you can subtract a single `50` from 75). The result of that last one is `25`.

Here's something you can do to help you understand a shell script. First:

```
$ export PS4="\$LINENO: "
```

The `PS4` prompt is for *debugging*. The default `PS4` prompt is `+` which isn't too useful. This changes the `PS4` prompt to the line number of the shell script that is being debugged.

Now, put `set -xv` and `set +xv` around the area of the shell script your trying to debug. In this case, you probably want to put it at the beginning and ending of the script. Here's my debugging output with the number 175. See if you can follow what's going on:

```
$ ./roman.sh 175
LIMIT=200
3: LIMIT=200
E_ARG_ERR=65
4: E_ARG_ERR=65
E_OUT_OF_RANGE=66
5: E_OUT_OF_RANGE=66

if [ -z "$1" ]
then
  echo "Usage: `basename $0` number-to-convert"
  exit $E_ARG_ERR
fi  
7: '[' -z 175 ']'

num=$1
13: num=175
if [ "$num" -gt $LIMIT ]
then
    echo "Out of range!"
    exit $E_OUT_OF_RANGE
fi  
14: '[' 175 -gt 200 ']'

to_roman ()
{
    number=$1
    factor=$2
    rchar=$3
    let "remainder = number - factor"
    while [ "$remainder" -ge 0 ]
    do
        echo -n $rchar
        let "number -= factor"
        let "remainder = number - factor"
    done  
    return $number
}

to_roman $num 100 C
35: to_roman 175 100 C
22: number=175
23: factor=100
24: rchar=C
25: let 'remainder = number - factor'
26: '[' 75 -ge 0 ']'
28: echo -n C
C29: let 'number -= factor'
30: let 'remainder = number - factor'
26: '[' -25 -ge 0 ']'
32: return 75
num=$?
36: num=75
to_roman $num 90 LXXXX
37: to_roman 75 90 LXXXX
22: number=75
23: factor=90
24: rchar=LXXXX
25: let 'remainder = number - factor'
26: '[' -15 -ge 0 ']'
32: return 75
num=$?
38: num=75
to_roman $num 50 L
39: to_roman 75 50 L
22: number=75
23: factor=50
24: rchar=L
25: let 'remainder = number - factor'
26: '[' 25 -ge 0 ']'
28: echo -n L
L29: let 'number -= factor'
30: let 'remainder = number - factor'
26: '[' -25 -ge 0 ']'
32: return 25
num=$?
40: num=25
to_roman $num 40 XL
41: to_roman 25 40 XL
22: number=25
23: factor=40
24: rchar=XL
25: let 'remainder = number - factor'
26: '[' -15 -ge 0 ']'
32: return 25
num=$?
42: num=25
to_roman $num 10 X
43: to_roman 25 10 X
22: number=25
23: factor=10
24: rchar=X
25: let 'remainder = number - factor'
26: '[' 15 -ge 0 ']'
28: echo -n X
X29: let 'number -= factor'
30: let 'remainder = number - factor'
26: '[' 5 -ge 0 ']'
28: echo -n X
X29: let 'number -= factor'
30: let 'remainder = number - factor'
26: '[' -5 -ge 0 ']'
32: return 5
num=$?
44: num=5
to_roman $num 9 IX
45: to_roman 5 9 IX
22: number=5
23: factor=9
24: rchar=IX
25: let 'remainder = number - factor'
26: '[' -4 -ge 0 ']'
32: return 5
num=$?
46: num=5
to_roman $num 5 V
47: to_roman 5 5 V
22: number=5
23: factor=5
24: rchar=V
25: let 'remainder = number - factor'
26: '[' 0 -ge 0 ']'
28: echo -n V
V29: let 'number -= factor'
30: let 'remainder = number - factor'
26: '[' -5 -ge 0 ']'
32: return 0
num=$?
48: num=0
to_roman $num 4 IV
49: to_roman 0 4 IV
22: number=0
23: factor=4
24: rchar=IV
25: let 'remainder = number - factor'
26: '[' -4 -ge 0 ']'
32: return 0
num=$?
50: num=0
to_roman $num 1 I
51: to_roman 0 1 I
22: number=0
23: factor=1
24: rchar=I
25: let 'remainder = number - factor'
26: '[' -1 -ge 0 ']'
32: return 0
echo
52: echo

set -xv
53: set -xv
exit
54: exit
```

Answer (score 0):

It simply takes a number and a 'factor' and the factor's roman representation and then simply loops and spits out the roman representation of number mod(factor)

Answer (score 0):

`to_roman()` takes three parameters: `number`,`factor`, and `rchar`.
The first thing the script does after defining the function is to call it with arguments of `$num` (which was passed in on the commandline as an argument to the script itself); the highest factor that the script can deal with: 100; and the Roman numeral representation of that factor (C).
Subtract the factor from the number to get the remainder, and if the remainder is zero or higher, print the rchar (C, in this case), update the number by removing the value of the character you just printed (100 here), update the remainder, and repeat.
If your initial number is less than 100, then the first remainder calculation will be less than zero, so nothing will be printed and the values won't change.
The script then deals with 90. The `num=$?` in between each call to to_roman() sets `$num` to the return value of the previous call.
I hope that's *reasonably* clear.