# calling function in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

the user will enter 3 numbers , and I want to calculate these number's roman values. I copy paste to_roman() function but its take 3 arguments . I'm confused . then I call this function in case statement.How can I implement this function for 3 numbers ? any implementation advice ?

```
to_roman ()   # Must declare function before first call to it.
{
number=$1
factor=$2
rchar=$3
let "remainder = number - factor"
while [ "$remainder" -ge 0 ]
do
 echo -n $rchar
 #echo $remainder
 let "number -= factor"
 let "remainder = number - factor"
done  

return $number       
 }

to_roman $num 10 x
num=$?
to_roman $num 9 ix
num=$?
to_roman $num 5 v
num=$?
to_roman $num 4 iv
num=$?
to_roman $num 1 i
```

Comment: Return values aren't for data in shell functions; they indicate success (0) or failure (a non-zero value whose meaning is specific to the function). A function should output a result, which can be captured with command substitution: `num=$(to_roman $num 10 x)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does this "Number to Roman" shell script work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619021/how-does-this-number-to-roman-shell-script-work)

Answer (score 4):

You just read the params in function like `$1 $2 $3` and so on.

`$#` being the total number of parameters

Depending on your implementation you may want to loop over the arguments for n argument support per @EitanReiner suggestion.

It is done with `$@`. For example:

```
for param in "$@"
do
    echo "$param"
done
```

In your case it probably would be an overkill since you get 3 parameters only. Anyway, you should check if you got exactly 3 parameters.

Comment: Also worth suggesting a loop over the arguments for `n` argument support.

Comment: sorry but I didn't understand what does your mean : You just read the params in function like $1 $2 $3 and so on. ?

Comment: You can pass any number of arguments - for n arguments you need to read values from $1 to $n.